# Does a Pokémon's gender when breeding with Ditto affect the offsprings' gender?

Tags: pokemon-seventh-generation

My sister has been breeding a bunch of Popplio because I want to FINALLY have a female. She started with breeding my male Primarina and a Ditto I traded her. After hatching around 20 eggs, she finally got a girl and put it with the Ditto instead of my male Primarina. Now, she's gotten 5 females out of 8 eggs.

So my question is: if being bred with another female Pokémon, do Ditto and that Pokémon have a higher chance of getting female offspring? Or is it just luck? I'll be trying this method with other Pokémon.

Answer (score 5):

Each Pokémon has its own gender ratio, which is not affected by who its parents are- or in fact anything at all. In Popplio's case, the male:female ratio is 7:1. In short, your sister simply got lucky.